# xrandr call makes it forget about secondary display

Tags: xrandr, display-settings, display

## In short

I have a laptop with an external DVI display which is hooked up to its Display Port (via adapter). When I rotate the internal screen using `xrandr`, it will forget about the secondary display. Calling `xrandr` multiple times does not have any effect. I have to power off the external display, wait for a while, call `xrandr` again and it finds the display.

## The details

I use Kubuntu 13.10 with Awesome WM instead of the regular KWin Windows Manager. Therefore, there are already two systems which do stuff with displays.

The laptop is a ThinkPad X220 Tablet, which has a Display Port on the device itself, and another one on the UltraBase docking station, which I use currently. The display is a Samsung SyncMaster 2443BW with a DVI to Display Port adapter.

Then, I use my own [think-rotate](http://martin-ueding.de/en/projects/think-rotate/) to rotate the internal (`LVDS1`) screen when I rotate the *physical* display (via ACPI hook). Said script uses `xrandr` to rotate the screen.

When I call `think-rotate`, it will glitch and give me the following `xrandr` output afterwards:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 277mm x 156mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

You see, that the `HDMI2` is completely missing. After letting all the power drain from the external display, calling `xrandr` again gave me the screen back and the following output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 277mm x 156mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1200      60.0 +
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        60.0  
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I looked into the `/var/log/syslog` and found the following within the debug output of the `think-rotate` script:

```
Jan  6 20:20:26 Martin-X220 colord: device removed: xrandr-Samsung Electric Company-SyncMaster-H9XS113172
Jan  6 20:20:26 Martin-X220 colord: Device added: xrandr-Samsung Electric Company-SyncMaster-H9XS113172
```

How can I triage this issue? I got other DVI and VGA displays around, I got another Display Port on the ThinkPad itself.

I assume that the problem is the interaction between something in KDE, Awesome WM (which reloads its config on every display change) and my `xrandr` calls.

## Follow-up

### Without Awesome WM, plain KDE with KWin

I just started KDE without Awesome WM. It did not only forget about the external display when I rotated, but it also caused severe compositing glitches. I found that `think-rotate` is called twice by the ACPI hook, so I am currently implementing a guard against that. Running it twice simultaneously might be the cause of the glitches. The forgetting about the display is caused when I call `think-rotate` manually, so that is not caused by running it twice.

### Without KDE, plain Awesome WM

Now I am just with Awesome WM, no KDE started. There is no problem. I saw here that it is called twice and work on that guard. It is called twice, but runs only one now. Apparently, the issue does not persist here. Although I do not like to admit, but with the information I currently have, KDE seems to cause the issue.

#### Update 2014-01-06 21:37+0100

Well, it seems like rotation works without problems with plain Awesome WM. When I put it onto the docking station, it does not see the external display right away. I have to power it off and call `xrandr` manually to get it working.

#### Update 2014-01-21 21:53+0100

I tried another DVI display, and I did not have any problems with it. When I go back to my Samsung SyncMaster, I get the issue again. Awesome WM alone caused problems, KDE with Awesome WM causes problems as well. It is still broken!

#### Update 2014-03-10 18:17+0100

The issue persists. I used a VGA cable to test it, and that did not appear to have the issue. My current workaround is to switch off the display, call `xrandr` and then turn it on again. Maybe Ubuntu 14.04 will fix that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue also persists when it is hooked up to different computers, also a Windows 7 machine. It is a hardware defect, I bought a new display a while ago.